# Failed to get driver instance for Derby 10.15

Tags: java, maven, derby

After upgrading a Java 12 maven project to [Apache Derby 10.15](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby/10.15.1.3/jar), a database unit test started to fail:

```
Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Release Notes](https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.15.1.3.cgi#New+Features) for Apache Derby 10.15.1.3:

> Derby has been re-packaged as a set of JPMS modules. This introduced a
> new jar file, derbyshared.jar, required by all configurations.

*derbyshared.jar* is the commons module that contains cross-module support utilities.

To fix the issue add [derbyshared](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.derby%20AND%20a:derbyshared) maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derbyshared</artifactId>
  <version>10.15.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

### Derby 10.15.2.0 update (Mar 2020)

According to the [release notes](https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.15.2.0.html) for version 10.15.2.0 the maven dependency issue has been fixed in [DERBY-7040](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-7040) ticket.

To fix the issue update derby version:

```
10.15.2.0
```

Comment: "derbyshared" has been added as a compile time dependency in version 10.15.2.0 to derby, derbynet, derbyclient and derbytools artifacts. Hence you do not need to explicitly declare derbyshared as dependency in your configurations.